# Removing an observer from an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have an observer on an UIView to adjust a UIWebView when the size is changed (e.g. on rotation of the device):

```
[[self view] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:nil];
```

Naturally I need to remove this observer when the view is dismissed (otherwise there is an exception). But where would I do this? I tried in dealloc, or in viewDidDisappear, but I get a SIGABRT when I do this.

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {       
    NSLog(@"Is moving %d - %d", self.isMovingFromParentViewController, self.isBeingDismissed);
    [[self view] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}
```

I tried to move it in earlier on ViewWillDisappear, but the same result.

Moreover, I am not completely happy with this later solution (even if it would work), as it will potentially also unload when the view is temporary out of view (i.e. with pageViewController), although that is not that big a deal for me at the moment.

Tracking the problem down to this item and trying to solve it has already cost me a day, so any suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Where do you add it?, Try dealloc method.

Comment: @Greg in dealloc, view is already unloaded

Comment: Actually strongly that works now, in dealloc. So I think I must be doing something funny somewhere else. I will review my code again line by line.

Comment: It works in viewDidDisappear,

Comment: why do you need to remove the observer? the doc says: _"The key-value observing `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method **does not** maintain strong references to the observing object, the observed objects, or the context."_, therefore, if the object is released it won't cause any issue. (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)

Comment: If I don't I get a SIGABRT. Might be a bug, I am not sure, but I need to remove it to prevent the crash

Comment: Check if your _addObserver_ and _removeObserver_ calls are balanced. Also use this method to remove observer _removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:_. This is recommended way(check the explanation given in __NSKeyValueObserving.h__)

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. It works in DEALOC. The problem was a balance, as in some circumstances the observer was not added, and as such caused a problem when tried to be removed. Now I have a check on that and it seems to work! Thanks for all the hints, it helps to see things which I glanced over before!